# Itext7 Fill and modiffy PDF in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext7

I am looking at [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170819135352/http://developers.itextpdf.com:80/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-5#1774-c05e02_fillandmodifyform.java)

I am trying the code below to run to fill a document in **c# asp.net**.

```
string src = @"C:\documents\BlankContracts\Document 50.pdf";
    string dest = @"C:\documents\BlankContracts\123.pdf";
    PdfDocument pdfDoc =
new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
    // add content
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
            Map<string, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
```

It keeps giving me an error on the part where it tries to get the list of fields. It keep asking me to create a class for Map.
If any one know how to do this please let me know. I have been going all over the place but couldn't find place where it shows how exactly can I fill out a PDF using the newer version **Itext7**
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the compiler want you to specify `Map`. Also, according to examples which you shared, you should change it

```
Map<string, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
```

to;

```
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
```

Comment: I see let me give this a try! Thanks for fixing me :)

Comment: Ok I was looking at the different example